# Using a current transformer

Tags: current-transformer

I have to measure a current of 500 A (50 Hz) using a 500 A/5 A CT with a uC. In my circuit, I have a 2.5 V reference/offset and the voltage will be measured about this offset value. There are low cost 5 A/5 mA PCB mount CTs available. Is possible to short the output (5 A) of 500 A/5 A, through the 5 A/5 mA, then use a burden resistor of 1k on the 5 mA and thus measure the 500 A current?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *Is possible to short the output(5A) of 500A/5A, through the 5A/5mA ,
> then use a burden resistor of 1k on the 5mA and thus measure the 500A
> current ?*

Yes, you can do this but you are compounding errors. I suspect that the main CT (500/5) will have a fairly decent specification regarding errors/tolerance. But, the 5 A/5 mA might significantly degrade the overall accuracy.

I understand the problem; to get a 2.5 volt peak with 5 amp peak output requires a resistor of 0.5 Ω and, if the AC is a sinewave, the RMS will be 3.536 amps. This will lead to a power dissipation in the 0.5 Ω burden of 6.25 watts.

So, my preference would be to use a significantly smaller burden such as 0.1 Ω and live with the 1.25 watts of dissipation. Of course, the peak voltage will now only be 0.5 volts but, a half-decent op-amp can restore this towards 5 volts p-p.

> *In my circuit, I have a 2.5V reference/offset and the voltage will be
> measured about this offset value.*

You say you want to use a 1 kΩ burden resistor with a current of 5 mA. If that current is RMS then, into a 1 kΩ resistor, the signal voltage would be between +7.071 volts and -7.071 volts superimposed on the 2.5 volt reference i.e. well beyond your MCU input range.

Comment: I was planning to use one of those generic PCB mount 5 A/5m A CTs. Will this error be linear , so that I can trim it in software ? In case I use the opamp, I am assuming i will need a dual supply (+/-) for the OpAmp ? Thanks much !

Comment: Yes I goofed up on the 1k resistor calculation, of course.

Comment: If you pick the correct op-amp it should work from a power rail of +5 volts and 0 volts but, bear in mind that you should aim for the maximum current to be slightly within that range (maybe 50 mV either side. The error of using a 2nd current transformer may not be very linear due to various things but, if you want, link me the data sheet for the 5 A/50 mA device.

Comment: Just a tad confused, The output from the CT will have a negative swing, so a rail to rail 5V OpAmp will not be able to handle it ?

Comment: Not able to get a datasheet , but this one : https://www.electronicscomp.com/5a-single-phase-ac-current-sensor-module

Comment: @MumbaiVerve you DC bias the CT output waveform to mid-rail on the op-amp. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: we procured a custom made 500A/ 50mA CT. With a burden resistor of 33E, we could feed the sense voltage directly to the uC ADC.

Comment: @MumbaiVerve they would have to be peak currents and not RMS currents. Also consider that you can add an extra parallel burden resistor to tweak the calibration because, although ADCs say they have a 3.3 volt span, it's usually a tad less and, I always leave 50 mV spare room at the upper end and the zero end just in case.

Comment: Its actually a 5V uC. 500A was the CT but the maximum current the equipment would actually use is about 400A, that too in small surges. Beyond 400A the equipment would be tripped after a settable period (ca. 4 sec).